# GenerationType.Identity not working after manually inserting records from database

Tags: sql-server, database, spring, hibernate

I am doing up a simple database insertion functionality where I want to auto increment the primary key index.

I am using Spring Boot Hibernate.
It works fine when I wiped the database and insert it using Spring as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JoinColumn(name = "EventID", unique = true)
private int eventId;
```

The index starts from 1 and its working perfectly normal.
However, after I insert some records manually into the database using MSSQL,
I am not able to run my code. The insertion of records using Spring does not work anymore.

Any idea what went wrong with my code ? Or do I have to do something with my database settings ? I need help on this but I cant seem to find anyone with the same issue on the internet.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add error log?

Comment: During insertion, have you specified any of the primary key values explicitly? This may cause the sequence to break.

Comment: During insertion, have you specified any of the primary key values explicitly? This may cause the sequence to break.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. I can insert, update and delete rows manually in my database and the indexing works still.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use GenerationType.AUTO instead

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
```